# Space in @ mention username and lowercase in link

Tags: php, regex, hyperlink, mention

I am trying to create a mention system and so far I've converted the @username in a link. But I wanted to see if it is possible for it to recognise whitespace for the names. For example: `@Marie Lee` instead of `@MarieLee`.

Also, I'm trying to convert the name in the link into lowercase letters (like: `profile?id=marielee` while leaving the mentioned showed with the uppercased, but haven't been able to.

This is my code so far:

```
<?php
function convertHashtags($str) {
    $regex = '/@+([a-zA-Z0-9_0]+)/';
    $str = preg_replace($regex, strtolower('<a href="profile?id=$1">$0</a>'), $str);
    return($str);
}

$string = 'I am @Marie Lee, nice to meet you!';
$string = convertHashtags($string);
echo $string;

?>
```

Comment: It's tough because what if you have `$string = 'I am @Marie Lee from Canada';`? Notice how even a powerhouse such as StackOverflow didn't bother with whitespace in @ mentions?

Comment: @MonkeyZeus, understandable. :c
What about the link? That one I really need it.

Comment: Your `convertHashTags()` function would have to check against a database to see if whatever `@` string you find is an actual user in the database and provide the `<a href>` intelligently. This is true regardless of whether you allow or deny spaces in the `@` mentions.

Comment: What about what link? Your code seems to work if you get rid of spaces in the  username

Comment: Why would you want your id to be a name? Names are hardly unique. Or is it just a username that you enforce to be unique?

Comment: @El_Vanja Not only unique but forever static.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may use this code with `preg_replace_callback` and an enhanced regex that will match all space separated words:

```sh
define("REGEX", '/@\w+(?:\h+\w+)*/');

function convertHashtags($str) {
    return preg_replace_callback(REGEX, function ($m) {
       return '<a href="profile?id=' . strtolower($m[0]) . '">$0</a>';
    }, $str);

}
```

If you want to allow only 2 words then you may use:

```
define("REGEX", '/@\w+(?:\h+\w+)?/');
```

Comment: Thank you so much, @anubhava. It worked as I needed! <3

Answer (score 1):

You can filter out `usernames` based on alphanumeric characters, digits or spaces, nothing else to extract for it. Make sure that at least one character is matched before going for spaces to avoid empty space match with a single `@`. Works for maximum of 2 space separated words correctly for a username followed by a non-word character(except space).

```
<?php
function convertHashtags($str) {
    $regex = '/@([a-zA-Z0-9_]+[\sa-zA-Z0-9_]*)/';
    if(preg_match($regex,$str,$matches) === 1){
        list($username,$name) = [$matches[0] , strtolower(str_replace(' ','',$matches[1]))];
        return "<a href='profile?id=$name'>$username</a>";
    }
    throw new Exception('Unable to find username in the given string');
}

$string = 'I am @Marie Lee, nice to meet you!';
$string = convertHashtags($string);
echo $string;
```

**Demo:** https://3v4l.org/e2S8C

---

If you want the text to appear as is in the innerHTML of the anchor tag, you need to change

```
list($username,$name) = [$matches[0] , strtolower(str_replace(' ','',$matches[1]))];
```

to

```
list($username,$name) = [$str , strtolower(str_replace(' ','',$matches[1]))];
```

**Demo:** https://3v4l.org/dCQ4S

Comment: Thank you so much for your help, @nice_dev . It worked in both the lowercase letters and the whitespace, however, for some reason I don't understand it deletes the rest of the text and only leaves the @ mention.

Comment: @Elena Can you let me know what was your input?

Comment: @Elena You mean `'I am @Marie Lee, nice to meet you!'` should be the innerHTML?

Comment: Yes, that text doesn't showed when echoed. I'm not sure why. I'm new in programming, sorry. :(

Comment: @Elena Updated my answer.

Comment: Thank you so much, @nice_dev !

Comment: @Elena You can also add underscores (_) to match them as well in those square brackets in the regex